# Inserting %20 instead of a space as a string

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have 600 records that I need to be linked on a website.  As clickable urls. But when I have the URL's, they only link to the 1st set of text before a space.  So is there a code in QGIS that I can put in to alleviate this.  I have tried:   replace( "url"," ") with "%20" But this requires some more work.

Comment: @Joseph that works, great job, I just put the with outside of the brackets.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Most welcome! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than just space that is not "URL safe".

If you are looking to URL encode your strings, try (for Python 2):

```
import urllib
url = urllib.urlencode(url)
```

This will handle spaces and a whole lot more.

[This post](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) has a quick table of the different characters you need to encode.

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 6):

You're close, you just need to put `%20` inside the expression surrounded by single quotes (used to denote **string**) instead of double quotes (used to denote **field names**).

So you could use:

```
replace("url", ' ', '%20')
```

Note that this replaces **all** spaces in each string so you may need to be mindful, especially in cases where you might have a space at the end of a string.

Comment: I need to finish a query to replace some text in the QGIS query.  I have got this so far:  replace("url", 'Y:\Natural Environment Record\', 'http://www.exmoor-nationalpark.gov.uk/PAttachments//NER/')  It through s a error.  I have a section of text that I need to replace.

Comment: @MattSully - What error does it throw? I'm guessing it's due to the slashes you used as it will read this if you don't escape them correctly.

Comment: Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected COLUMN_REF, expecting COMMA or ')'

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Comment: try `'Y:\\Natural Environment Record\\'` with doubled backslashes

Comment: @Jimmy - That answered his [next question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255230/changing-a-string-of-text-in-qgis) :)