# Changing a string of text in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have some text in a column in QGIS, I am using field calculator, I need to replace it with some other text.

This is what I have so far:

`replace("url", 'Y:\Natural Environment Record\', 'http://www.exmoor-nationalpark.gov.uk/PAttachments//NER/')`

It doesn't seem to like this, any ideas?  This goes along side the answer to my last query getting spaces removed and to include them as %20 (Réf. [Inserting %20 instead of a space as a string](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255215/inserting-20-instead-of-a-space-as-a-string))

Comment: That worked again, thanks @Joseph.  I then do the replace("url", ' ', '%20') one again and I should have links to my url's.  Thanks ever so.

Comment: @Joseph I'll delete my answer as I had misunderstood the question. Can you then post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @MartinHügi - Don't bother ;)

Comment: That's very gracious of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
replace("url", 'Y:\\Natural Environment Record\\', 'http://www.exmoor-nationalpark.gov.uk/PAttachments//NER/')
```

Comment: it is all the records I need to change from Y:\Natural Environment Record\ to http://www.exmoor-nationalpark.gov.uk/PAttachments//NER/ but the text forms part of a string?  How do I select out just that piece of text?

Comment: This is what I have at the moment, I know it's wrong but am I going in the right direction?    replace("url", 'Y:\Natural Environment Record\' , '(http://www.exmoor-nationalpark.gov.uk/PAttachments//NER/)',')

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string that the text forms part of?